# How to use custom CSS for ONLY one page while using 'header' and 'footer' structure in php

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently working with PHP to develop a website. I'm using "header.php" and "footer.php" so I don't have to repeat the same things over and over. However, I use custom CSS for some of the pages which are changing elements in other pages. In other words:

```
<?php
require "header.php"
?>
<main>Page Body</main>
<?php
require "footer.php"
?>
```

I'm looking for a way to include the CSS file I need somewhere ELSE than on the header because it is affecting other pages and I only need this formatting for this specific page. 
Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes oyu can seperate the css stylesheet in `stylesheet.php` and remember to include it underneath the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables inside the header function, which you declare in the main page.

```
<?php
$customheaders = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extrastuff.css">';
require "header.php"
?>
<main>Page Body</main>
<?php
require "footer.php"
?>
```

And in header.php you can use [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to see if the variable has been defined and is not `NULL`:

```
<?php
if (isset($customheaders)) {
  echo $customheaders;
}
?>
```

Obviously there are better ways to create templates to handle these kinds of exceptions, but considering the question I think this basic approach is good enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your header.php file contains the link tags to your CSS files the conditional logic would have to exist there to include the proper stylesheet. There are many ways to approach this. You could for example start by checking the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then conditionally add a link tag to an alternate stylesheet.

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/example.php') { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extrastuff.css">
<?php } ?>
```

Even prettier:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/example.php'): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extrastuff.css">
<?php endif; ?>
```